# Galaxy Note 4 Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to test my mobile application on Galaxy Note 4.

Are there any emulators available, that I can install on my windows machine and test the application. Is there any way I can test the application without purchasing the physical device.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: There is no Google Note 4. There is a Galaxy Note 4 and a Google Nexus 4. Which one do you mean?

Comment: 2,560 x 1,440 screen size

Comment: my bad... Galaxy Note 4...

Comment: Me too. Is there no way to just configure the stock SDK emulator to be like a Note 4?

Answer (score 1):

You can run Android emulator version 4.4 on-demand on AWS with Ravello and run your particular device and run the tests. It will probably cost you very less.

http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/android-emulator-on-amazon-ec2-and-google-cloud/

Let me know if you have questions or need more information.

Manisha Arora

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, 6.0 and 6.0.1 are both considered API 23 and Android N is considered API 24. When I create an Android Virtual Device with API 23, the AVD shows OS Version 6.0

Given this information, I do not think there is any way to run an emulator that has Android 6.0.1 installed.